# Tableview inside another table view with dynamic height for inner tableview

Tags: uitableview, swift3

im new to iOS development.The thing im trying to achieve is to have a tableView inside another  tableView and must have selection for items in that inner tableView. There are some problems facing when i implemented this.

- i need to have a dynamic table view height (ie,for the first time loading ,inner table view should only have a height to show 3 cells and on clicking a show more button in the outer tableview cell ,the outer table view cell will expand and show the remaining cells in the inner table view)
- On selecting a cell in the inner tableView,  the same cell in the inner table view cell all other cells are also getting selected.

Im attaching the code i did and image of what im trying to achieve.
[Please click here to see the desing i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJuxF.png)

**Outer Main Table View methods**

```
    extension Explore:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 13
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = exploreTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "exploreCell", for: indexPath) as! ExploreAlbumPosting

        if isExpanded{
            cell.showMoreBtn.setTitle("Show Less", for: .normal)
            cell.showMoreBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_arrow_drop_up"), for: .normal)
        }
        else{

            cell.showMoreBtn.setTitle("Show More", for: .normal)
            cell.showMoreBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_arrow_drop_down"), for: .normal)

        }

        cell.showMoreBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showMoreBtnTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.showMoreBtn.tag = indexPath.row
               return cell


    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if isExpanded && selectedIndex == indexPath{

            return 180 * numberOfRowsInInnerTableView
        }
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return  215
    }


}
```

**show More Btn Tapp action**

func showMoreBtnTapped(sender:UIButton){

```
let row = sender.tag
self.selectedIndex = IndexPath(item: row, section: 0)
isExpanded = !isExpanded
self.exploreTableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndex!], with: .automatic)
self.exploreTableView.scrollToRow(at: selectedIndex!, at:UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: true)
```

}

**inner Table view Methods ( This is extended to the customcell class - UITableViewCell of outer table view)**

```
extension ExploreAlbumPosting:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = innerAlbumTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExploreAlbumInnerCell", for: indexPath)

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 92

    }
}
```

Please help me.Thank you